# Drill down report in power bi after a comparaison in power query

Tags: merge, powerbi, alert, powerquery, drilldown

I am comparing two datasets with Power Query.

The two datasets are as follows:

Fist dataset:

```
  |---------------------|------------------|    
  |       Planet        |     Species      |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    Neptune          |      45 453      |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |      Mars           |            76    |
  |---------------------|------------------|
```

Second dataset:

```
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|     
  |       Planet        |     Species      |     SubSpecies   |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    Neptune          |      45 453      |      BOUB        |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |      Mars           |            76    |      BIB         | 
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    Neptune          |      45 453      |      BOUB        |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |      Mars           |       77         |       BOUB       |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |      Mars           |       77         |       BIB        |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I look if one "couple" (Planet/Species) exist in one file but not in the other, and it it is the case I underline this in my report.

The power BI report shows this, in my example, because the couple Mars/77 is new:

```
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |      Mars           |       77         |
  |---------------------|------------------|
```

I identify what is missing by simply merging queries in power query.

However I would like to have the ability to "drill down" in sub-speicies.
For example, lets say that for the first time a species is observed in one planet in one of the file, I would like to have the ability to show in the report the sub-type.

In this case, the output, besides showing that for the first time speicies 77 has been observed on Mars, would show this:

```
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |      Mars           |       77         |       BOUB       |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |      Mars           |       77         |       BIB        |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I do not know how to do that and I do not know if doing this in power query is possible or if I would need to use DAX in parallel or in complement.

Comment: Did you tried with Matrix visual? That's a powerful visual for setting category and sub category one under another.

Comment: No...but my biggest issue is that I am "loosing" values from one step to another. When I join in power query with right and left anti to seewhat is "new in each file", I first earease the column "subspeicies" and supress the duplicate in order to compare. If I would I could not compare. This is my biggest issue.